# App rejected on play store because of Manage_External_Storage even though my app does not use this permission

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, google-play-console

I have an app built using Xamarin for android.

I keep getting the same email saying my app is using Manage_External_Storage and keeps getting rejected even though it's not in the manifest. The app at some time had requested that permission but we have removed that from the manifest. Even the Play console App bundle explorer reads the correct permissions. Below are the permissions from for that app bundle from the app bundle explorer in Play Console

```
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, 
android.permission.CAMERA, 
android.permission.INTERNET, 
android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC, 
android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT, 
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

I have also checked the manifest of the compiled .aab in android studio and it does not have that permission in there.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="26" android:versionName="1.0.26" android:installLocation="0" android:compileSdkVersion="30" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="11" package="com.test.app" platformBuildVersionCode="30" platformBuildVersionName="11">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC" />
    </manifest>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are using CAMERA where you store these images ?

Comment: We were storing the  images in the app data store. Issue has been resolved as someone pointed out in another thread that we need to either 
a. update all the other tracks
b. delete other tracks 

I went with b. and it worked. Stupid design from playstore. They should mention this info in the email that which track is causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the Permission, you need to update the build number on Internal Track. you have to update the build on every track(Open testing, Closed testing, Production, etc.) even if permission are disabled in android 11.
Here are some threads you can refer to:

[Google Play store continuous rejection due to NOT compliant with the All Files Access Permissions policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69534826/google-play-store-continuous-rejection-due-to-not-compliant-with-the-all-files-a/69933431#69933431)

[Google Play App Rejection - Not a core feature - Use of All files access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70035032/google-play-app-rejection-not-a-core-feature-use-of-all-files-access)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I found the above threads by myself but couldn't believe that it worked. Talk about crazy issues. Marking as answer. Sadly don't have enough points to vote yet.